# A table with several columns in addition to a date/time column. How to query and avoid duplicate dates stamps?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in SQL Sever with the below date/time stamp column in addition to other columns. How can I query this table to avoid getting duplicate dates in my result? I don't care which time stamp is returned by the query. I just want unique dates for example only one 05/05/2018 and if possible its corresponding time stamp and its corresponding RPM value. Similarly one 06/11/2018 with its corresponding rpm value and its time stamp and so on.....

```
RPM         Date-time
7932    06/04/2018 16:30:01 +00:00
8314    06/11/2018 16:30:00 +00:00
8748    06/12/2018 20:52:10 +00:00
8067    06/05/2018 20:15:00 +00:00
8063    06/05/2018 12:45:34 +00:00
8067    06/05/2018 20:15:00 +00:00
8070    06/07/2018 12:02:16 +00:00
8144    06/08/2018 20:30:00 +00:00
8144    06/08/2018 20:30:00 +00:00
8314    06/11/2018 16:30:00 +00:00
8314    06/11/2018 16:30:00 +00:00
8314    06/11/2018 16:30:00 +00:00
8748    06/12/2018 20:52:10 +00:00
8748    06/12/2018 20:52:10 +00:00
9046    06/14/2018 12:14:46 +00:00
9192    06/15/2018 11:13:23 +00:00
9274    06/15/2018 20:30:04 +00:00
9293    06/20/2018 18:47:10 +00:00
9562    06/22/2018 12:30:00 +00:00
10141   06/25/2018 18:26:13 +00:00
10443   06/28/2018 18:35:21 +00:00
10500   06/29/2018 11:14:42 +00:00
10500   06/29/2018 11:14:42 +00:00
10500   06/29/2018 11:14:42 +00:00
10506   06/29/2018 15:45:22 +00:00
10506   06/29/2018 15:45:22 +00:00
10506   06/29/2018 15:45:22 +00:00
10526   07/05/2018 14:14:49 +00:00
10526   07/05/2018 14:14:49 +00:00
10526   07/05/2018 14:14:49 +00:00
10526   07/05/2018 14:14:49 +00:00
```

Comment: Edit the question add expected result.

Comment: If you're only querying those 2 columns then a distinct select is enough.  If you expect to select the other columns then you should add them to the example and provide your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think distinct should work :

```
select distinct RPM, Date-time
from table t;
```

However, i assume your table has other columns too if so, then you can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by rpm order by date-time) as seq
      from table
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: I don't think this will achieve what the user wants, I think what they mean is that they only want one of each rpm record returned (this applied to the first part of the answer).

Comment: I think you want partition by rpm, date-time (this will allow you to pick one row from sets of rpms by date).

Comment: Question has been modified for what I want in the results

Answer (score 1):

If you need the Distinct of the RPM and Date part of the "Date-Time" then it can be achieved as below:

```
SELECT Distinct RPM, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Date-time,111) FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast and group:

```
select rpm,cast([Date-time] as date) as _date
from table t
group by rpm,cast([Date-time] as date)
```

Comment: @KeithL- It still gives duplicate dates see result below. I think its happening because the time stamps are different for the same dates
    2018-06-05
    2018-06-05
    2018-06-07
    2018-06-08
    2018-06-11
    2018-06-12
    2018-06-14
    2018-06-15
    2018-06-15
  2018-06-20
    2018-06-22
    2018-06-25
    2018-06-28
    2018-06-29
    2018-06-29
    2018-07-05

Comment: the dates with multiple RPM values ended up as duplicates. That was not your question.

Comment: You have to decide what you want when more than 1 RPM shows up. Take out of the group by and aggregate somehow (max,Min, Avg)

Comment: @keithL-You mean like this? select min(rpm),cast([Date-time] as date) as _date from table t group by cast([Date-time] as date)

Comment: @Alli That will give you an answer. You should base it on what your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by RPM but you would then have to provide an aggregate function for each column returned (or also group by them):

e.g.

```
SELECT RPM, MIN(Date-Time) FROM TableName GROUP BY RPM
```

Comment: @SBFrancies-It still returns duplicate dates. See result below                
06/04/2018 16:30:01 +00:00
06/05/2018 12:45:34 +00:00
06/05/2018 20:15:00 +00:00
06/07/2018 12:02:16 +00:00
06/08/2018 20:30:00 +00:00
06/11/2018 16:30:00 +00:00
06/12/2018 20:52:10 +00:00
06/14/2018 12:14:46 +00:00
06/15/2018 11:13:23 +00:00
06/15/2018 20:30:04 +00:00
06/20/2018 18:47:10 +00:00
06/22/2018 12:30:00 +00:00
06/25/2018 18:26:13 +00:00
06/28/2018 18:35:21 +00:00
06/29/2018 11:14:42 +00:00
06/29/2018 15:45:22 +00:00

Comment: So you don't need to get every rpm?